# Filemaker 11 Perform Script in another file

Tags: filemaker

I want to run a script in one file (A) from another file (B). In file B I have a script step: Perform Script [“email test” from file:”A”]

File A is password protected, so when the script runs a login dialog box comes up, but I want this to run automatically in the background without having to enter a password. File B is a timed file? How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Add the same username and password in File A as File B.

Then in File A goto File -> File Options and tick Log in using and fill in the credentials.

File A will open without asking for a username/password and when it opens File B to call the script it will pass on the authentication details.

Answer (score 0):

Offhand I can think of three techniques you can use to run the script in File A without needing to enter the password each time.

First, on the Mac there is the option to "Remember my password" when you log into File A.  If you check this, FileMaker will look up the password when File B performs the script in File A and should automatically log in.  I don't know if such a feature exists in Windows but it might be possible to do the same thing there.

Second, once a user is authenticated with FileMaker, FileMaker will try to use the same authentication credentials for any other database that the first database tries to open.  So, as Adam suggests, you can add the same Username and Password used in File A to the Security section of File B.  From there you would change the File Options to auto-login with the Username and Password you transferred.  You should now automatically log in to both File B and File A.

Third, you could manually log into File A and just leave it open.  This technique isn't as robust as the first two as you would need to manually log in again each time the file shuts down or connectivity is lost.

#### A Few Words About Security

File A probably has a password for a reason.  When doing techniques like this it is certainly best to think about security and what people should be allowed to access if they gain access to your computer.  At minimum your computer should probably require a password both at login and whenever the screensaver is deactivated just to ensure that people without authorization aren't able to access File A when they shouldn't.

Remember that, with the second technique, anyone who gains access to File B can now access File A with your credentials so you definitely want to be careful with File Sharing and letting others use your computer.